# Pass value from while loop in session

Tags: php, session

I have a small problem/question...

I have made a while loop that's echo a href link. How can I give the $_Session the correct value for the selected ncrnummer?

This is my code:

```
$query1 = "SELECT id FROM `ncr_input` WHERE projectnummer = '".$_POST['Projectnummer']."'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
                $ncrnummer = $row['id'];
                if ($row['id']) {
                    $_SESSION['ncrnummer'] = $row['id'];
                    echo "<a href=\"http://localhost/ptrg%20NCR%20applicatie/UpdateNCR.php\">{$ncrnummer}</a>";
                    echo "<br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A common method would be to add the ID onto the URL of your link - `UpdateNCR.php?id=2` (for example), then when this page is called it will use `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: @NigelRen, Thanks! That solved the problem